# how to use the AjaxUrl property (ExtInfoWindow) in Infobox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the task of updating googlemaps version 2 to version 3.

I have code from version two that uses ExtInfoWindow to get "pop-ups" with information and after extensive reading on the links below i found that the equivalent of this method is either Infobox or InfoWindow. I decided to go for Infobox.

Read links:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html

http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/extinfowindow/docs/reference.html

Code from version 2:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openExtInfoWindow(
        map,
        "mapwindow",
        "<img src='/images/ajax-loader.gif'>",
        { beakOffset: 0, paddingX: 60, paddingY: 45, ajaxUrl: '/templates/GoogleMapsMarkerInfo.aspx?id=' + page + '&epslanguage=<%=CurrentPage.LanguageBranch %>' }
        ); 
};
```

As you can see from the code i have the property ajaxUrl which i have not been able to find in either InfoWindow or InfoBox. I figured that i could perhaps take the above AjaxUrl and put it inside the content property(check code below) but after reading the documentation on the content property a few times i realized that this would not work.

My attempt:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                var myOptions = {
                 content: {"<img src='/images/ajax-loader.gif'>",'/templates/GoogleMapsMarkerInfo.aspx?id=' + page + '&epslanguage=<%=CurrentPage.LanguageBranch %>'}
                ,disableAutoPan: false
                ,maxWidth: 0
                ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(60, 45)
                };
            var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
            ib.open(map, marker);
}
```

firebug error message:
http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/8646/firebugerror.png

I have been searching for a about 5 hours for the equivalent of AjaxUrl from the ExtInfoWindow without any luck.

If anyone has the answer to my problem im thankful for the answers and if it is not a problem i would appreciate if you can link me to some documentation about the solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the docs, 'content' takes a string or a Node.

> Content to display in the InfoWindow. This can be an HTML element, a
>   plain-text string, or a string containing HTML. The InfoWindow will be
>   sized according to the content. To set an explicit size for the
>   content, set content to be a HTML element with that size.

You should just perform your own ajax request for the content and supply that to the infowindow/infobox.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution!

Thanks Rick for trying to jump-start my brain.

was pretty simple once i understood what Rick ment.

I performed a ajax request and the data i got back was an html document.

And as Rick mentioned the content property can display this information so i just set the data i got back to the content and voila!

the code:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: '/templates/GoogleMapsMarkerInfo.aspx?id=' + page + '&epslanguage=<%=CurrentPage.LanguageBranch %>',
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data){
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content:data
                    });
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
             });
```

thanks Rick!